# How can I change the content of <style type="text/css">

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page in HTML and I need to replace the content inside tag

```
<style type="text/css">
</style>
```

injecting the content of another **.css** file hosted on the same domain.

Any idea how to do it in javascript?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      h1 {color:red;}
      p {color:blue;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doing this in JavaScript may cause flickering. It would be better to do it on server side if possible.

Comment: @ GibboK: Do you *really* need to inject the text into the `style` element, or just add the styles to the document? If you just need to add the styles to the document (which will have the same effect as injecting text into the `style` element), [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15335082/157247). It's really easy. If you actually have to inject content into the `style` element, that's a little bit harder (though not *hard*), but I'm curious why you would need to do that. :-)

Comment: DownVoter, please add a comment so I can make adjust my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add those styles, you don't need to inject the content into the `style` element, just link that other file as a stylesheet:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "/path/to/the/file.css";
document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].parentNode.appendChild(link);
```

That will "inject" the relevant styles into the document.

[Live Example using your markup](http://jsbin.com/igogoy/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/igogoy/1/edit)

Comment: My problem is I do not have Link Tag, only style. Thanks for posting

Comment: @GibboK: All browsers have the `link` tag. The above doesn't require that you have anything on the page you haven't said you have in your answer. What it does is ***add*** a `link` for the stylesheet containing the styles you're trying to add to the document. That ***adds*** those styles to the document, just like adding text to a `style` element does.

Answer (score 4):

Add an id attribute to the style tag.  Use this hook to change the contents of the style tag with Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<style id="myStyle" type="text/css">
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
</style>

<h1>Something</h1>
```

**Javascript**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myStyle");
elem.innerHTML = "h1{color:blue;}";
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/4xAHr/

Comment: I would need to populate the innerHtml with the CSS that it is present in another file.. any ideas?

Comment: Are you opposed to using jquery?

Comment: jquery it is a great tool, but I cannot use it on this project. Please let me know